# JavaScript addEventListener() method

Tags: javascript

Is `addEventListener()` method a "standalone method" or a part of some Object? Like `round()` and `floor()` methods are associated with `Math` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addEventListener()` is not a stand-alone method, it is part `EventTarget` which is a DOM interface implemented by objects that can receive events and may have listeners for them.

Try using `addEventListener()` method alone and you will understand.
Check out [EventTarget on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget).

Answer (score 0):

Should be part of DOM related methods. In other words it's not standalone.

Answer (score 0):

> The addEventListener() is an inbuilt function in JavaScript [citation link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-addeventlistener-with-examples/)

Also here is what console log shows console.log(addEventListener):

[console.log of this function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ia7JN.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).